# Why does Firefox quantum doesn't show the values of dropdown?

Tags: html, firefox, html-select

This is how it looks in Firefox.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXUku.png]

Even after clicking the dropdown and choosing a value, it doesn't show up the value.

But chrome does show the first default value and also the values chosen by the user.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh1YP.png]

By the way, it was working fine in previous version of Firefox.

This is the code

```
<select id="code" name="code" class="dropDown" style="width: 185px; padding-right: 195px;" onChange="changeTextBox();">
                                <c:forEach items="${code}" var="code">
                                    <option value="${code.value}">${code.key}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I did remove the extensions and restarted firefox, and still it didn't work https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1186485